# Why does "quadratic" describe second power when "quad" means "four"?

Tags: etymology, prefixes, mathematics, word-formation

In mathematics, *quadratic* means "involving the second and no higher power of an unknown quantity or variable". But the prefix *quad-* usually describes something that has to do with four, such as *quad-core processor* and *quadrilateral*. Why does "quadratic" describe second power when "quad" means "four"?

Comment: Quadratic comes from "quad" meaning square; when you raise something to the second power, you square it.

Comment: @NateEldredge ... or, at least in the case of mathematics, _quartic._ I can't say I've ever actually heard the word "quadric."

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: You're right, of course.  Brain failure.  ([Quadric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric) is actually a second-power thing again.)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Because the second power is a square, and [a square has four sides](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=quadratic). In fact the word *square* itself [comes from *quad-*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=square&allowed_in_frame=0), too.

Comment: I like the sound of "squaratic equation," come to think of it.

Answer (score 137):

Because *quadratus* is the Latin for "square" due to there being four sides on a square.

The second power of a number is called its *square* because if we have an integer, and construct a square with that number of items on each side, the total number will be its second power. E.g. a 4×4 square having 16 items:

```
* * * *
* * * *
* * * *
* * * *
```

It is also the case that the area of a square with a real number length side, can be measured in terms of the square of that number.

Related language trivia: In the middle of the 16th century, while *squared* was being used in this sense by some, it had yet to become current, and there was a brief use of *zenzic*, which means the same thing (via a Latinised, Germanicised, Italian translation from Arabic; it's a convoluted etymology). This form was productive so *zenzizenzic* meant the 4th power (squared square), *zenzicube* the 6th (squared cube) and for the 8th power we have *zenzizenzizenzic*, which is often claimed as the English word with the most Zs in it. It's a doubtful claim though, first there's nothing stopping us from using *zenzizenzizenzizenzic* to have even more, and second there seems to be about nobody using it any later than 1560 other than in sentences containing the phrase "has the most Zs".

Comment: While the accepted answer got there first, you explain the rationale more clearly. Also, the discussion of zenzic is charming. I once had a math professor who wrote that on the board and asked for speculations on its mathematical meaning. Not one of us guessed it correctly.

Comment: All I can think about reading this post is Scrabble.

Comment: @emragins you wouldn't be the first, but since there's only one z and two blanks, the word is impossible.

Comment: I'm very bad with math. `if we have an integer, and construct a square with that number of items on each side, the total number will be its second power.` I don't get how this works. If I have a square and each side is the number 2, the total is 8, not 2^2 = 4. If I have a square and each side is the number 3, the total is 12, not 3^2 = 9. How exactly does that `number of items on each side` get applied?

Comment: @teylyn added a diagram to the answer to show what I meant.

Comment: +2 for zenzizenzic, -1 for "due to there being" ;-)

Comment: @teylyn you're adding up the numbers on the four sides of the square. You should be counting the number of spaces in the square (this is equivalent to multiplying the number on one side by itself, which is the same as squaring). You're calculating the perimeter of the square instead of the area.

Comment: Joined this community just to upvote this, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

*Quadri-, quadru-, quadr-* is a Latin prefix related to the verb *quadrare* ‘to make square’, *quadratus* ‘square’ etc. *Quad* is simply an English shortening of *quadrangle*, *quadruplet* etc. So *quadri-* and *quad* are actually the same word.

Comment: Well, strictly it comes from making an adjective out of the obsolete English *quadrate*, that's directly from the Latin *quadratus*; there was no shortening to *quad*.

Comment: Yes, quad is originally a shortening of the typographic term quadrat (not quadrate).

Comment: *Quad* is found in several different senses which are each shortenings of various cognates. None of them influenced *quadratic* though, which is < English *quadrate* < Latin *quadratus*.

Comment: Ah, you were addressing the other statement in the question. My mistake.